# Can you make a program similar to OpenBTS for CMDA using the gr-cdma library?

Tags: gnuradio, cellular-network

Can you create a program like [OpenBTS](http://openbts.org/) for CDMA using [this](https://github.com/anastas/gr-cdma) library?

Answer (score 2):

You can, in theory. In practice, CDMA is but a very, very small aspect of ba very complex standard such as umts; all the other code necessary to create something that acts correctly on a standards-compliant network will largely outshadow just the CDMA-related code.

It might also be worth noting that communication standards put hard limits on things like reaction time - something that gr-cdma might not meet with your hardware.

A communication standard is much more than it's medium access mechanism.